# Is it good practice to create a controller with index action only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am about to create a single admin page (/admin) and was trying to figure out the best way to approach this. All solutions I find seem to be too complex for my needs (admin page will have a single purpose of editing one of the resources). Controller with only one action seem to be the simplest solution, are there any other options I should consider before doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things to consider.

- If the page is used for editing one resource, why is at `/admin` instead of at `/<resource>` or `/admin/resource` or `/admin/<resource>/:id` ? You can use nested routes to create admin namespaces if needed. Potentially you could even namespace `:admin` in your routes and set a root in the admin namespace to a particular controller instead of making a dedicated controller.
- There's nothing inherently wrong with creating a controller for one action, sometimes it does make sense. But usually such pages aren't specifically for editing one resource - they're things like dashboards or special features that don't map neatly into the resource/model hierarchy.
- If you find that you need several static pages it's common (per the Rails tutorial among other sources) to group them in one controller.

You might read through the Rails routing guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) if you haven't.

Comment: I read about namespaces and it seemed like an overkill for my needs. The decision to make admin page is not mine unfortunately, so I can't skip that. I'm happy to read your second bullet - it is indeed kind of a dashboard (edit resource + some additional statistics). I usually went for the third bullet option (Pages controller) but it was always more than one custom action only.Thanks for a great response, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use HTTP basic authentication and use a `before_action` with `only` option to trigger it only for the action you want to password protect.

```
class ResourceController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate, only: [:admin_edit]

  def admin_edit
    # your action code here
  end

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "admin" && password == "admin@123"
    end
  end

end
```